# Как различаются числа signed и unsigned если старший бит это знаковый?

Tags: типы-данных, хранение-данных

Я тут повторял способы хранения двоичных кодов и никак не могу понять, как будут выполняться арифметические операции для двух чисел: 1-е знаковое (signed) 2-е беззнаковое (unsigned)? Ведь у них может быть одинаковая запись.

Получается у signed старший бит означает знак числа, а у unsigned старший бит означает само значение.

Но как понять какое из них signed а какое unsigned, ведь числа записываются одинаково: например число `173` (`10101101`) unsigned и число `-45` (`10101101`) signed у них совершенно одинаковая запись.

В данном случае я рассматриваю только 8 битные числа, т.е. от -127 до 127 и от 0 до 255.

Comment: Никак не различаются, программный код сам решает, как интерпретировать хранящиеся в памяти данные

Comment: ALU их в самом деле не различает, схемы сложения, умножения и деления одни и  те же, реализующие арифметику по модулю N (количеству бит в регистре). В результате операции формируются биты переноса и переполнения. Вот их трактовка и отличает знаковые от беззнаковых. Т.о. программист, определяя тип переменной, говорит компилятору какие команды условного перехода  надо использовать при сравнении и нужно ли выполнять  расширение старшего бита при загрузке переменной в регистр (для переменных размером меньше регистра)

Comment: А тогда зачем нужны прямой, обратный и дополнительные коды? Разве они не интерпретируются программой?

Comment: Речь о дополнительном коде (остальные коды  -- это уже давняя история, для арифметики в них  нужны разные схемы)

Comment: Спасибо, avp. Тогда получается, что в ALU используются дополнительные коды для вычислений?

Comment: Да, в современных ALU используется **дополнительный код**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Языки программирования, *в которых программист вынужден заниматься внутренним (бинарным) представлением чисел*

- т.е. определить их как `signed` или `unsigned`

*никогда не позволяют операции, в котором один операнд типа `signed` и другой `unsigned`:*

- или выдают ошибку,
- или по умолчанию переводят их в один тип.

Как вы правильно написали, ни человек, ни компьютер не сможет определить только на базе бинарного представления числа, если оно со знаком или без знака. Потому в языках как C/C++ число сначала должно определит, и даже когда в определении отсутствует `signed` или `unsigned`, всё равно оно будет одним из них по умолчанию.

С другой стороны, в языках как Питон вы ничего не определяете, вы просто напишете `x = 173` или `x = -45`, незная (и не должен знать) ничего о его внутреннем представлении.

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем так.
Например, **unsigned short**

```
173 = 0x00AD = 00000000 10101101
```

Возьмем **signed short**

```
-45 = 0xFFD3 = 11111111 11010011
```

А вообще, если в двоичной системе счисления взять два одинаковых числа, то всё будут решать типы данных.

Вот, например, поиграйтесь с переводом в разные системы счисления [здесь](https://binaryconvert.com/index.html)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. В данном случае я рассматриваю только 8 битные числа, т.е. от -127 до 127 и от 0 до 255

Comment: Понятно. 
Ну и в этом случае 173 и -45 будут отличаться в двоичной системе